# NVIDIA GeForce GT750M drivers for Ubuntu 13.10 on iMac

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, imac

I have just got a new iMac 14.3 with 21.5' display. It has Intel i7 processor and NVIDIA GeForce GT750M graphics card with GPU (Device ID: 0x00fe9). I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 on it (dual boot with refit). Everything works fine apart from graphics. It is clear that graphics' not accelerated, and there are no drivers suggested in the "Additional drivers" section. I have tried to

1. Install nvidia drivers from the repository.
2. Download nvidia drivers and install them manually.
3. Follow instructions [here](http://falkvinge.net/2013/02/15/how-...12-10-quantal/).
4. Follow instructions [here](http://dedoimedo.com/computers/ubunt...il-nvidia.html).
5. Follow instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681...tricted-driver).
6. Install bumblebee.
7. Play around with xorg.conf file.
8. Blacklist nouveau.

As you may guess, nothing worked. The weirdest thing is, that when I boot from a LiveCD, it picks up screen resolution and all the rest correctly, though when I install the system to my Hard Drive it clearly does not have proper drivers. Does anyone have any suggestion what to do?

Comment: Have you verified the current drivers even supports your mobile card?

Comment: Yes, and I have downloaded the correct file from the official website

Comment: Thats not exactly what I asked.  I asked if the drivers supports your card.  I have no doubt they do but always good to verify.

Comment: ehm, if you can suggest a way to check it with 100% guarantee... I'm pretty sure I've downloaded the correct drivers when I've downloaded them, but it'd be nice to have an answer for your question for nvidia-current as well.

Comment: The supported products are listed on the download website for the file and in the release notes.

Comment: so as it was assumed, the graphics card is supported

Comment: But then you have exhausted all extant possibilities, AFAIK. You can start playing with the module parameters. You find them by means of modinfo module_name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually very simple: just boot with `nolapic` instead of `acpi=off`.